# How to pour tubeless sealant without removable core valves

Tags: tubeless, sealant

I have an Ultegra UST wheelset and tubeless tyres on them. After suffering some punctures I decided to run them with a tubeless sealant. The problem is that the sealant's manual instructs you to remove the valve cores and pour the liquid through the hole but my rims came with standard integrated valves. I ended up removing part of the tyre off the rim and pouring the liquid through the slit and then quickly using the pump to seat the tyre back in the rim. However, for some reason this is apparently not quick enough as it results in some considerable amount of the liquid spilling out.

Is there any weird trick to doing it effectively? Note that *"buy different valves"* is not going to be considered an acceptable answer (even though I may consider upgrading eventually.)

Comment: Also are you using UST tires? Or "Tubeless Ready" tires? I only ask because the tire bead is different, UST uses a more square profile bead to  lock into the bead seat. Tubeless ready are made for standard beads, while they can be made to work it won't seal and hold quite as well if that is the case, just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling the tire from the rim is the easiest way.

If you want to avoid spilling any sealant, have a friend or stand hold the wheel off the ground so the tire can keep its shape.

---

I've seen people use a needle & syringe on the internet somewhere, but that doesn't strike me as the best idea. I like my tires sans holes to start with.

Comment: as in, a syringe through the tire?

Answer (score 2):

Some sealant seepage is normal once the tire is on the rim, the only real way to do it without pushing it through the valve is to pour it directly into the tire. I like to pour a tiny bit and then roll the tire in your hands spreading a thin layer around the surface of the tire. Just a weird personal thing i do, not necessary really.

Then install one bead to the rim, install the other bead leaving a small space unset, a small funnel will help pour the remaining specified amount into the opening. Seat the bead and then hit it with an air compressor (if available) and spin it one good time, bounce it on the ground, spin it again and your good to go.

It would be worth saving for some tubeless valves in the future that have removable valve cores as the process is a lot easier and can be done without messing with the tire seating. Especially if you use a sealant that comes with one of the easy fill tubes such as Orange Seal.